# can we get all the classes that extends a specific class

Tags: java

Lets say

```
Class A
{
    public void method(); 
}

//Class File  
Class B extends A
{

}

//Class File
Class C extends A
{

}
```

Is there a way to get all classes that extends Class A. I tried using javassist but it didnt work.

Comment: your question is not clear. what did you mean by getting all classes inside a project? you can have many packages in a java project and in every package you can have multiple classes. but I am not understanding your question literally!

Comment: i want to list down all the class that have extended Class A

Comment: I don't really understand why you would want to do that but try `instanceof` to know if it is a subclass then you can print it or store it in wherever you want.

Comment: Java does not define "project", but some IDE's do. If you are not using an IDE, you have to define what you mean by "project".   Also, given class A, do you also want to list all classes that extend a class that extends A, and so on? Some IDE's (like Eclipse) have an option to display the entire class hierarchy starting at a specified class.

Comment: @FredK I am not using any IDE.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly using instanceof will be difficult because i will have to use it for each and every class to check. But i want to get it by my agent code. That wheather any classes have extende Class A or not. Is that Possible?

Comment: Can't figure why would you need to do this. Perhaps you want to give this project a shot?
https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: @SamuelKok I want to intercept only the classes that extends Classs A.So i need to list out all the classes that extends Class A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10 to do this.

For example:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("path.to.package");
Set<Class<? extends MyClass>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyClass.class);
```

I haven't tested Example.

Comment: I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate may be because of jar mismatch issue. Tried with some different versions of reflection jar. But still getting the same exception

Comment: Do you use Maven to assembly and dependency management? Or you add jar to the classpath?

Comment: If you don't use the Maven then you have to add missed dependencies into the classpath.